# Spring 3 MVC Validation with Hibernate, error after hasErrors?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am just learning Spring3 Validation with Hibernate.  I wanted to add Validation so I pyt the @Valid in the function call and add the code into the formbean but I get the following error if the formbean has a error.  if it does not have a error it works great.  please et me know what I am NOT doing right.  thanks

Source:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveArticle(@Valid @ModelAttribute(" article") Article  article, BindingResult result) 
{
System.out.println("In ModelAndView");
// Adding code to check for errors;
if (result.hasErrors())
{
   System.out.println("In ModelAndView-hasErrors");
   return new ModelAndView("addArticle");
}
articleService.addArticle( article);
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/articles.html");
}
```

Console output:

```
In ModelAndView
In ModelAndView-hasErrors
Mar 25, 2011 9:41:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'article' available as request attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra whitespace: `@ModelAttribute(" article")`

Your model attribute is bound as `" article"`, whereas your form tries to redisplay a model attribute named `"article"`, which is obviously not bound.

Comment: thanks it works now.  being new to Spring 3 MVC Validation with Hibernate and you please tell me any good PDF's I can download and read

Comment: @Java: Actually, I don't know any resource with a thorough explanation of these concept.